# JMS - Items Not going to out Queue

Tags: jmeter, queue, jms

I am using the JMeter JMS Publisher to send an item to a display - OK, but when I validate the item using JMS Subscriber it errors with 404 ? Looking at the JMS browser they are in the In Queue but not buffering to the out Queue ? I can force it through the JMS browser but cannot understand why the JMS subscriber part is not working ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [JMS Subscriber Source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/jms/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jms/sampler/JMSSampler.java#L281)

```
    if (sampleCounter == 0) {
        res.setSuccessful(false);
        res.setResponseCode("404");
        res.setResponseMessage(sampleCounter + " samples messages received, last try had following response message:"+
                res.getResponseMessage());
```

JMeter returns status 404 when the subscriber gets 0 results on attempt to consume the messages from the queue.

If you see the messages in the queue using the browser application it means that your JMS Subscriber configuration is not correct.

You can [enable debug logging for JMeter's JMS protocol](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms" level="debug" />
```

Once done you should see the JNDI configuration, queue names, etc. so you could cross-check it with the values in the JMS Browser application and amend JMeter configuration to match it.

Comment: Hi, just found out that my colleague runs the exact jmeter test plan with no differences but does not get the 404 error ? The Subscriber destination field is the same as mine. Any clues... proxy settings / firewall / network settings / account credentials. This is really weird. I even cloned his Ubuntu VM and still got the error. Any help please